# How to remove same word from another column in ms-excel?

Tags: excel, ms-office

I have a 25000 medicine list in excel. The First column is Name second column is type then others column. But there is a problem. in the NAME column, there is the same word as TYPE column. Now I want to remove Type column word from Name column. Is it possible?

I tried replacing by CTRL+H. but it's time-consuming.

main file
https://redpen.io/vo4ddf8a7fabb96a79

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two ways to do this. Manually in the worksheet with an "IF" function an then copying over the results. OR in code. Which way works best for you?

Comment: I m new in excel. Thanks though I will learn this function now then I will try to apply.

Comment: https://redpen.io/vo4ddf8a7fabb96a79 here you can see the main file. can you please help?

Comment: So from the looks of your file, you want to clear column A if it CONTAINS anything in column B. This is different than your original statement. It could still be done, but I am thinking that in vba code would be best. Lets be sure first of what you are asking. If column A contains a word from column B, do you want to CLEAR column A or just remove the matching word?

Comment: If you just want to remove the matching word, then in a blank column, put this formula "=LEFT(A1,LEN(A1)-LEN(B1))".
Auto-fill this column all the way to the bottom.
This will give you a column with the duplicate values removed. Copy that entire column and select the first cell in column A and right click and select paste special. Choose to paste the VALUES and this will over write the existing values with the new ones and there you have it. Let me know if you have trouble.